# Cannot redirect to page using url parameter found in form

Tags: python, django, url, httpresponse, url-parameters

I am trying to get the module code from the module foreign key in my form and display the posts that belongs to it using HttpResponseRedirect but I'm getting error : 
'str' object has no attribute 'code'. How can I solve this?

Traceback:

```
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars

response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
request <WSGIRequest: POST '/forum/'>
self    <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x03A88970>
wrapped_callback    <function forum_modules at 0x038DF618>
callback    <function forum_modules at 0x038DF618>
resolver_match  ResolverMatch(func=forum.views.forum_modules, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=forum_modules, app_names=[], namespaces=['forum'])
resolver    <RegexURLResolver 'mysite.urls' (None:None) ^/>
callback_args   ()
response    None
middleware_method   <bound method CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view of <django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware object at 0x03AAAFD0>>
callback_kwargs {}
urlconf 'mysite.urls'
response_is_rendered    False


code = module.code ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
module  'CA'
request <WSGIRequest: POST '/forum/'>
```

I changed the following

```
 module = request.POST.get('module')
 code = module.code
```

to : `module_id = request.POST.get('module')` 
as it contains the code of the module. But I am now getting this error.

```
Reverse for 'forum_modules' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'module_id': None}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: please give error trace back

Comment: You have fetched the string `module` from `request.POST`. To go from that string to a `Module` object, you'll have to do a lookup e.g. `Module.objects.get(...)`. We can't say what the lookup should be, because you haven't said what the value of `module` is. Is it the primary key, code, or something else?

Comment: module is a foreign key in Post. It has primary key as code. But when I use module in my form, i get a dropdown of the list of module titles. I need the code to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you're trying to find an URL that isn't there. You have the `forum_modules` named URL that has no parameters, but you're trying to find a `forum_modules` named URL which has either `module_id` or `module` as a parameter.

For something like this to work you should have something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<module>\d+)/$', views.forum_modules, name='forum_modules'),
```

if module would be a number. The difference is the named pattern in the URL, which reverse then tries to replace with whatever you give it. If it doesn't find a matching pattern you get that error.

Alternatively, if you're looking to have a URL parameter like `http://example.com/?module=123`, the query parameter part (`?module=123`) is not handled by `reverse`, you have to append that yourself, something like:

```
import urllib
reverse("forum_modules") + "?%s" % urllib.urlencode({"module": code})
```